# imgtrefseq vs imgtblast

Tags: untagged

In [IMGT ftp-download (flat files) page](https://www.imgt.org/download/LIGM-DB/), there are 2 optional fasta files (imgtblast and imgtrefseq) with their corresponding blast databases to download. Is the only difference the syntax and additional annotation in the refseq files?

Thank you!